# Webpack imagenes background css

Tags: css, symfony, webpack

Tengo 3 CSS diferentes los cuales contienen imagenes ***.png** de background. He probado varias soluciones leidas por aquí para compilarlos correctamente con Webpack encore pero siempre obtengo el mismo error en el css compilado.

`background:url([object Module])`

Esta es mi configuración de webpack.config.js:

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

// Manually configure the runtime environment if not already configured yet by the "encore" command.
// It's useful when you use tools that rely on webpack.config.js file.
if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    // only needed for CDN's or sub-directory deploy
    //.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')

    // .addLoader({ test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|htc)$/i, loader: 'url-loader' })

    //Common
    .addEntry('app', [
        './assets/js/mycustom/my-custom.js',
        './assets/js/app.js',
    ])
    .addEntry('custom1', './assets/js/affiliates/custom1.js')
    .addEntry('custom2', './assets/js/affiliates/custom2.js')
    .addEntry('custom3', './assets/js/affiliates/custom3.js')

    // When enabled, Webpack "splits" your files into smaller pieces for greater optimization.
    .splitEntryChunks()

    // will require an extra script tag for runtime.js
    // but, you probably want this, unless you're building a single-page app
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()

    /*
     * FEATURE CONFIG
     *
     * Enable & configure other features below. For a full
     * list of features, see:
     * https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html#adding-more-features
     */
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    // enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    // enables @babel/preset-env polyfills
    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
        config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
        config.corejs = 3;
    })

    // enables Sass/SCSS support
    // .enableSassLoader()

    // uncomment if you use TypeScript
    //.enableTypeScriptLoader()

    // uncomment to get integrity="..." attributes on your script & link tags
    // requires WebpackEncoreBundle 1.4 or higher
    //.enableIntegrityHashes(Encore.isProduction())

    // uncomment if you're having problems with a jQuery plugin
    .autoProvidejQuery()

    // uncomment if you use API Platform Admin (composer req api-admin)
    //.enableReactPreset()
    //.addEntry('admin', './assets/js/admin.js')
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

He intentado por todos los medios varias soluciones, desde implementar un custom loader empleando `url-loader` o `file-loader` pero sin éxito. No termino de entender por que razon al compilar el CSS no se referencia correctamente a la imagen. Debería quedar algo así:

`background:url(/build/imagen.7g7hjhb.png)`

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo muy bien la pregunta, pero los principales errores en estos casos són:
 - El punto en el nombre puede dar errores, mejor utilizar "-"o "_" de separador.
 - El formato de la imagen no sea el correcto.
 - La ruta realmente no este apuntando a la carpeta contenedora de las imagenes